# Hide plasma panel by default for all users?

Tags: rhel, kde, plasma

I'm attempting to auto hide the plasma panels, the top and bottom task bars, by default for all users. There is an application users run that requires them to turn on autohide for both top and bottom panels.
I would like to automate that so the autohide is configured by default at login. I did find that I could modify the user's home directory: `~/.kde/share/config/plasma-desktoprc` and place `panelVisibility=1` after each `[PlasmaViews][#]`

This far I have a script that will add it at login, but I feel there is a better way. I didn't find anything easily modifiable in `/usr/share/kde4` or `/usr/share/kde-settings` to set this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could place the desired `plasma-desktoprc` in `/etc/skel`. Then, when a new user is created, this will be automatically added to their home directory.

If unfamiliar with `/etc/skel` see a decent summary [here](http://www.linfo.org/etc_skel.html)

Comment: Oh yes, I heavily use skel. It would work for the local user created to validate the OS as deployed, but I'm going to have ldap users logging in as well, as such they don't get a copy of skel. I have a few scripts that copy some generic ssh keys and setup shared ssh user account access, I suppose it would be trivial to just add this file to the copy.

Comment: Ah yeah, in that case that may be best. I can't really think of an alternative if the LDAP users aren't being provided with home dirs on the network e.g. using `autofs`. See if anyone comes up with a better solution then. I'm quite interested myself.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out. Modify a generated `plasma-desktoprc`. Under each `[PlasmaViews][x]` add `panelVisibility=1`
`panelVisibility` has four settings:

- 0 = Always Visible
- 1 = Auto Hide
- 2 = Windows can cover
- 3 = Windows go below

Place this modified `plasma-desktoprc` in `/usr/share/kde-settings/kde-profile/default/share/config`. I then added a post login script to copy the `plasma-desktoprc` if it didn't contain the desired settings.